# What would be the pros and cons of packing a lot of logic in a single C statement?

Tags: c, coding-style

```
....
if (i<lim -1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF))
{
    ....
}
....
```

what would be the pros and cons of writing the code in this fashion.

Comment: Belongs on code review.

Comment: Opinion-based, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a lot of logic, but it's already a good example of why you shouldn't do it: it leads to code that's difficult to understand and difficult to debug; it's a lot like packing a single sentence with a multiple ideas that are, perhaps, related but not *so* related that they shouldn't be in their own sentences -- in both cases, the underlying issue is that it's easier to hold a single, simple thought in your head than to process several competing thoughts, even if those thoughts are somehow complementary.

Simple is better.

Let's look at the particular code in question:

```
if (i<lim -1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF)) {...}
```

There's a problem here, and it's actually a pretty simple one: your parentheses don't match up. You've got three `(` but four `)`, so the compiler is going to complain. Should we fix this little problem by removing the second `)` or the fourth one? It happens that it doesn't really matter -- the result should be the same either way. That won't always be the case.

What you consider simple and how you choose to break up the ideas in your code is often a matter of taste. It's not always true that writing a stack of nested `if` statements is really easier to understand than a single `if` with multiple clauses. Consider:

```
if (i<lim -1) {
    if (c=getchar() != '\n') {
        if (c!=EOF) {
            ...
```

I'm not sure that really helps much. Personally, I'd opt for something like this:

```
if (( i < lim-1 ) &&
    ( c=getchar() != '\n' ) &&
    ( c != EOF ))
{ ... }
```

It's the same code, but arranged in a way that makes reading it easier. Looking at it, it's easy to say to yourself: "*if* the following three things are all true...", and it's easy to pick out each of the three conditions.

Comment: Could you give us an example how you would restructure that statement? For me the only thing it lacks is some proper parenthesis to make it easier to read but if something should happen if and only if 3 conditions are met, how would you write that in your code?

Comment: @junix I thought I just did? See the part that says: *Personally, I'd opt for...*

Comment: Oh, sorry, I still had the old version of your post on my screen :-) Now I'd agree.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the answer from @Caleb. That piece of code is very simple and has next to no logic. Someone reads from input buffer until either the buffer limit is reached or no more characters to read. It's a fair piece of code but nothing to discuss really.

So, forget about that piece of code.

Comment: I am new to C and i was wondering if writing the same code in the stlye shown below would make a difference.

(i<lim -1)
{
if (c=getchar()) != '\n' )
{
if( c!=EOF)
{
.......
}}}

Comment: The initial piece of code seems to be easier to understand

Comment: @user2582265 This isn't specific to C or any other language, they all use grouping symbols like `()` and `{}` in a similar way. Just keep writing and do whatever you tend to feel most comfortable with. Too many grouping symbols can water down the code, but too few and you can't see what connects to what.